# Why td max-width does not work in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="table-wrapper" ng-app="groupModule">

    <table class="tablify stylable" ng-controller="listController">

        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th>Group Name</th>
                <th>Parent Group</th>
                <th>Effect</th>
                <th class="col-actions">Edit</th>
                <th class="col-actions">Delete</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">

                <td>{{ group.groupName }}</td>
                <td>{{ group.parentGroupName }}</td>
                <td>{{ group.effect }}</td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-edit"></button>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"></button>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 75%;
}

table.stylable {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

table.stylable th {
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #353535;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

table.stylable tr {
    background-color: #EEE;
}

table.stylable td {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}
table.stylable th:last-child,
table.stylable td:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}

table.stylable tr th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

table.stylable tr th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

table.stylable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

table.stylable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

table.stylable tr:hover:not(.row-details):not(.selected) {
    background-color: #AAA;
    color: white;
}

table.stylable tr.selected {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
}

table.stylable tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table.stylable tr.selected td {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table.stylable table {
    width: 100%;
}

table.stylable td,
table.stylable th
{
    padding: 3px 8px;
    min-width: 65px;
}

.btn-edit,
.btn-delete
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    border: none;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    height: 0;
    background-size: contain;
}

.btn-edit {
    background-image: url(../images/Edit.png);
}

.btn-delete {
    background-image: url(../images/Delete.png);
}

.col-actions
{
    max-width: 80px;
}
```

If anybody wants then here is angular code:

```
var groups = [{groupCode: 1, groupName: "Branch / Divisions"},
              {groupCode: 2, groupName: "Capital Account", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 3, groupName: "Current Assets", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 4, groupName: "Current Liabilities", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 5, groupName: "Direct Expenses", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 4, nature:"Expenses"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 3, effect: "Trading Account"}},
              {groupCode: 6, groupName: "Direct Incomes", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 3, nature:"Incomes"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 3, effect: "Trading Account"}},
              {groupCode: 7, groupName: "Fixed Assets", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 8, groupName: "Indirect Expenses", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 4, nature:"Expenses"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 2, effect: "Profit & Loss Account"}},
              {groupCode: 9, groupName: "Indirect Incomes", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 3, nature:"Incomes"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 2, effect: "Profit & Loss Account"}},
              {groupCode: 10, groupName: "Investments", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 11, groupName: "Loans (Liability)", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 12, groupName: "Misc. Expenses (Asset)", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 13, groupName: "Purchase Accounts", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 4, nature:"Expenses"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 3, effect: "Trading Account"}},
              {groupCode: 14, groupName: "Sales Accounts", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 3, nature:"Incomes"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 3, effect: "Trading Account"}},
              {groupCode: 15, groupName: "Suspense A/c", natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 16, groupName: "Bank Accounts", parentGroupCode: 3, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 17, groupName: "Bank OD A/c", alias: "Bank OCC A/c", parentGroupCode: 11, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 18, groupName: "Cash-in-hand", parentGroupCode: 3, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 19, groupName: "Deposits (Asset)", parentGroupCode: 3, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 20, groupName: "Duties & Taxes", parentGroupCode: 4, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 21, groupName: "Loans & Advances (Asset)", parentGroupCode: 3, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 22, groupName: "Provisions", parentGroupCode: 4, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 2, nature:"Liabilities"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}},
              {groupCode: 23, groupName: "Reserves & Surplus", alias: "Retained Earnings", parentGroupCode: 2, natureOfGroup: {natureOfGroupCode: 1, nature:"Assets"}, effectOfGroup: {effectOfGroupCode: 1, effect: "Balance Sheet"}}];

angular.module('groupModule', [])
       .controller("listController", function($scope){
           $scope.groups = groups.map(function(g){ return {
               groupCode: g.groupCode,
               groupName: g.groupName,
               parentGroupName: groups.filter(function(x){ return x.groupCode == g.parentGroupCode; })[0] == undefined ? 'Primary' : groups.filter(function(x){ return x.groupCode == g.parentGroupCode; })[0].groupName,
               nature: g.natureOfGroup == undefined ? '' : g.natureOfGroup.nature,
               effect: g.effectOfGroup == undefined ? '' : g.effectOfGroup.effect
           }});
       });
```

Here is the JSFiddle reproducing issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/n7qmt8wt/

Comment: assign `max-width` to `<th>` instead of `<td>`

Comment: There is not a single instance of max-width in your css.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal I have already applied max-width to th. Can you see col-actions class? that is applied to th and td both.

Comment: @AdrianBrand There is col-actions class. See its max-width in css.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal I have updated my question with jsfiddle link

Comment: @AdrianBrand I have updated my question with jsfiddle link

Comment: In Chrome if I edit the value to be smaller the col-actions cells get smaller so it seems to be working in your fiddle the way I would expect.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Try to resize the fiddle's output to a larger width. It does get biiger.

Comment: @Vishal can't you use `width` only, as it will solve your issues, its just your last two col will always have `80px width`.

Comment: @vishal your td width <80 px so you can not use max-width property, you can increase the td width so increace your min-width.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay No, I can't just use width because I would like to have support for resizing as well. I mean for different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For table cells the `width` property should be used, as the 'min-width' and 'max-width' is undefined for table cells. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

> The effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables,
>   table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.

You just have to remember that cells shrink also below the given width since CSS caluclates the width of the cells depending on the table's width and the cells content.

So what you can use is the [fixed table layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout) what will change the algorithm behind the width calculation.

**But** what I usually do is to make my own grid with `div` elements, instead of using tables (because of their weird behavior).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on using your own grid instead of table

Comment: So, instead of using ``table``, ``th``, ``td`` you just use ``div``s (alternatively you can reset the table elements to ``block`` / ``inline-block`` elements, I think that's better, because of the semantic meaning of the elements). Of course – this reset will break your layout since block and inline-block elements behave totally different than table elements – and you have to rearrange the elements, so it just looks like a table – but while this process you have the whole flexibility and the elements will exactly behave like you want it.

Comment: I can't stress enough how easy it is to work with `div` instead of `table`. After struggling to get the `table` aligned properly for the better part of today, stumbled upon this answer. With `div`, I was done in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have already applied `width:100%` in table and td or th will decide their width dependent to table width.

For this you have to remove `width:100%` from table only then you would be able to apply `max-width` or `min-width` in td/th

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n7qmt8wt/3/

**Another good option people use for table is**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

> The table-layout CSS property defines the algorithm to be used to layout the table cells, rows, and columns.
>
> fixed value:
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

This totally depends on you that you would use this or not but this is a great method to keep the table `100%` wide with each `<td>` or `<th>` with same size.

Comment: If I remove width:100% then I can't get my table to full stretch. I don't want to loose that.

Comment: I have tried table-layout: fixed. But it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Please check width:100% and table-layout: fixed in jsfiddle

Comment: No, its not working. Try to resize the output in jsFiddle you can see the width of buttons growing

Comment: did you understood the meaning of `table-layout` i just gave u this as an option because this will give equal width to all the cells

Comment: I have equal width to all cells even without table-layout: fixed